# Arxiv email address issue

Tags: arxiv

Can I provide different email address within the paperwork in the end of it ? Other than what I've used to register myself on arxiv.org ? Is it okay to have different emails for contact purposes specifically?

Comment: Papers do not actually even need an e-mail address. So there should be no problem to use a different e-mail address in your paper.

Comment: @DCTLib thanks a lot for this clarification!